# ios exception analyse NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, exception

My app crash with a NSInternalInconsistencyException like this

```
 Exception reason：NSInternalInconsistencyException
        Exception name：Can't cancel on a touch that isn't already active!
        Exception stack：(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191a4d1d0 <redacted> + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019048455c objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191a4d08c <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x000000019250502c <redacted> + 112
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000197fd1960 <redacted> + 404
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000197fcf970 <redacted> + 1648
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001908d61fc <redacted> + 24
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001908d61bc <redacted> + 16
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001908e43dc <redacted> + 928
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001908d99a4 <redacted> + 652
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001908e634c <redacted> + 572
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001908e60ac <redacted> + 124
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000190adf2a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000190aded8c start_wqthread + 4
)
```

How do i analyse the log? Like What do those number tags mean,"+ 148" "+ 56"...? How to detect the code that have invoked this exception.

Comment: I would start with the *human readable* sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a crash from a release build of the app, or do you have it in Xcode? If in Xcode please provide the code causing the crash?

Looking at your report, the line

> Can't cancel on a touch that isn't already active!

seems very telling. I would look through your code for anywhere you are interacting with a `UITouch` object, or perhaps a `UIGestureRecognizer`. My guess would be that somewhere you are manually calling to cancel an interaction that you should not be, and there is a race condition where that can sometimes happen after the system has already cancelled the touch (or vice versa, I guess).